# How to animate a property of a UI element defined inside a ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox of a data template which consist some textblock and combobox. I want to apply some animations on textblock and combobox like i want to change textblock color on double click. 
So for I tried creating storyboard color animation for that but I got following error

```
Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Color'.
Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
```

my storyboard animation code is something like this :

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="onSubmitAnimation">              
    <ColorAnimation From="Green" To="Red" Duration="0:0:5" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" />        
 </Storyboard>
```

I wonder whether I'm going in right way or not, or there is something better way to implement 
color animation on textblock inside datatemplate of listbox? 
Would love to get all possible suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
 Here is the code I'm using to start storyboard;

```
 ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
 Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("onSubmitAnimation") as Storyboard;
 Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, item);
 sb.Begin();
```

I guess I should pass object of textblock in setTarget function but i dont know how to get correct object of textblock inside listboxitem.

My listbox is named as Entrylistbox so I can access any item of listbox through it but not sure how can i access textblock and apply animation on that.

**Edit 2:**
Still I'm not able to apply animation on textblock, I'm getting following error

```
 The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Here is my DataTemplate code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" >
  <Canvas Height="62"  Width="600" Background="White" >
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=IconBinding, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter} }" 
           Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="10" Height="35"/>

      <TextBlock Name="textblock1"  Padding="5" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10" 
                 Background="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="35" 
                 Foreground="Gray" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" 
                 FontFamily="/TimeSheet;component/Resources/#Open Sans Extrabold"  
                 Width="60" FontWeight="Bold">
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}H">
          <Binding Path="HoursBinding" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </Canvas>
  </DataTemplate>
```

I want to change background color of "textblock1" .

Comment: `TexBlock` does not have `Color` property. It has `Background` and `Foreground` brush. Did you try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"` or `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"`?

Comment: I tried with these properties, though its not giving any error but Its  not changing the color of textblock .

Comment: How do you start your `Storyboard`? What is the target? You'll need to post more relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your problem is accessing the `TextBlock` element from the containing `ListBoxItem` object that you have. This is a fairly common problem and is discussed in detail in the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

However, in short, you need to use the `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` method to access the UI elements defined within the `DataTemplate` that has been applied to the object in the `ListBoxItem`. Here is a short example from the linked page:

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem 
// Note that the ListBox must have 
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem =
    (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);

// Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
MessageBox.Show("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: "
    + myTextBlock.Text);
```

Comment: hey @Sheridan Thanks for answer! , I tried your answer, but still I'm having some issue. I have added my _datatemplate_ code in question.

Comment: Stating that your error says something (from your question) is less helpful when you haven't explained where the error is thrown. Also, I'm not sure how to explain the situation any better than that Microsoft page does.

Comment: I'm getting this error in "Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem" step. in this line '  ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);'

Comment: Wow, really??? Try looking at the very next code example on the linked page, where you will find the implementation of the `FindVisualChild` method. Come on now... this is basic stuff... surely you can do *this* bit by yourself?

Comment: Yeah! Got it, Will try it tomorrow. Thanks for Help